# How can I deploy a discord.js bot to Cloud Functions?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, discord.js

I want to deploy a Discord bot running on discord.js to Firebase Cloud Functions but I can't get the bot to run in Firebase. If I use nodemon it runs perfectly but if I use firebase deploy it will not start the bot.

Here is my current code:

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

require('dotenv').config();
const token = process.env.TOKEN

const Discord = require('discord.js')
const Client = new Discord.Client();

Client.on('ready', () => {
    Client.channels.find(x => x.name === 'main-cannel').send('bot is deployed')
    Client.user.setGame(`The Cult | ${Client.guilds.size} servers`)
    Console.log('test')
});

Client.login(token);

//is is not working but de basic
//export.App = functions.... {Client}
exports.app = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    response.send("Test");
});
```

Comment: Are there any error messages? how are you starting it? a bit more information is needed here.

Comment: Sorry @ThomasReichmann if i run nodemon app.js it runs but if i do firebase deploy  --only functions it is not running

Comment: Is ther no body that can help me whit this question ^^ ??

Comment: What happens when you deploy your code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This may not be the best combination of google cloud platform services, since cloud functions where not designed with this in mind. You can just host your Discord bot on a compute engine machine.

If you want to use the dynamic scaling have a look at [Discord Microservice Bots](https://gist.github.com/DasWolke/c9d7dfe6a78445011162a12abd32091d) where DasWolke describes what microservices are. Hey also included his javascript code to split up the different services for Discord.

What you can do on Google cloud platform specifically, is creating a VM with the [Gateway](https://github.com/DasWolke/CloudStorm) running. This needs to run 24/7 and should be lightweight. You can use an f1-micro (which is free) for this though google recommends a g1-small for the task.

The gateway should filter the events you are looking for (because Discord sends a lot of events and you don't need most) and send the data to [cloud function](https://cloud.google.com/functions) or [cloud run](https://cloud.google.com/run) (you can send the data via [pub/sub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub)). In my experience, a cloud run has much shorter startup times so I went with that.

Inside your function, you receive the data do with it what you want. If you want something in Discord (send a message, manage channels, ...) you can use [SnowTransfer](https://github.com/DasWolke/SnowTransfer) for that. SnowTransfer just calls the rest API on discord.

Answer (score 4):

Put `client.login(token)` into where `response.send("Test");` is. This will prompt your bot's code to execute upon an HTTP request.

In `https://us-central1-<your project ID>.cloudfunctions.net/app`, replace `<your project ID>` with your project's ID.

If Firebase Hosting gives you the URL `example-123.web.app`, your project ID is `example-123`. You can also get your project ID through the console: open the Firebase console, select your project, click the settings icon, go to "Project settings," and its ID is on the second line of the table.

For this to work, you have to move your token straight into the code. You can't use a shell file like .env.

In the end, your code will be:

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const token = 'whatever the token is';
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const Client = new Discord.Client();

Client.on('ready', () => {
    Client.channels.find(x => x.name === 'main-cannel').send('bot is deployed')
    Client.user.setGame(`The Cult | ${Client.guilds.size} servers`)
    Console.log('test')
});

exports.app = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    response.send("Test"); // Do not delete this! Your request will time out if you do.
    Client.login(token);
});
```

As Gabber235 noted, this is probably not the best Google Cloud Platform service to use for this, and you should probably use Compute Engine.

Comment: When possible, please make an effort to provide additional explanation instead of just code. Such answers tend to be more useful as they help members of the community and especially new developers better understand the reasoning of the solution, and can help prevent the need to address follow-up questions.