# How can I properly connect Realtime Database to a Discord.js bot hosted by heroku

Tags: javascript, heroku, discord, discord.js

Now I understand that this is a loaded question but every time people make videos showing how to do this, they run the project locally. With heroku I'm lost on where im supposed to find a build pack or something to remove the error saying firebase is not a module.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new `file` on your main `folder` called `.gitignore` and you should type

```js
node_modules
.env //If you have these one, you should ignore it too
```

**Clarifications:**

1. Since `heroku` can deploy your own `node_module` you need to use `.gitignore` to hide your `node_modules` and let the heroku `install` all of your `package` for your bot.
2. If you have `.env` for your `bot token` you need to `ignore` it too, since there's a step to put your `token` in heroku too.

Comment: So then can I just add my firebase config and all that and it will work?

Comment: Just to clarify, if this `firebase` of yours, did you installed it as `package` or just a `local file` in your folders?

Comment: firebase is a database system ran by google often used in android apps and websites, I just dont know how to connect it to my discord bot

Comment: This might help you with your problem [Look with this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58731014/how-can-i-deploy-a-discord-js-bot-to-cloud-functions)